# How do I fix this Subversion MKCOL error?

Tags: svn

When I commit I get this error from Subversion:

```
bash-2.05b$ svn commit -m "testing subversion, still"
Adding         baz
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: MKCOL of '/viper/!svn/wrk/6b9bcd38-b2fe-0310-95ff-9d1a44098866/sandboxes/ohammersmith/trunk/baz': 405 Method Not Allowed (http://svn.example.com)
```

Comment: When it happened to me it was because instead of doing a mkdir baz, I did a cp -pr ./foo/ ./baz --thereby getting the ./baz/.svn/ dir containing SVN info for the foo dir.  To fix it, I just did rm -rf baz/.svn and then was able to svn add, svn ci ...

Answer (score 112, accepted):

This happens when you have added a directory that someone else has also added and already committed.  The error message on a commit is really confusing, but if you do an `svn up` instead you'll see this message:

```
bash-2.05b$ svn up
svn: Failed to add directory 'baz': object of the same name already exists
```

To resolve the issue, remove your directory (or move it aside) and do an `svn update` to get the version on the server and re-do your changes.

As a general rule, be sure to do `svn update` since the error messages tend to be more helpful.

Comment: Sometimes the problem arises but an update is useless because oddly enough Subversion does not try to retrieve the directory from the repository; this is often the case when using Tortoise SVN. The solution is then to access to the repository itself, e.g. using the Tortoise SVN "Repo-browser", and to delete the directory. Then you should be able to add and commit your local data to the repository.

Comment: Pragmateek - that can be dangerous if you are not the only one working on files in that folder.  The safest way is as Otto suggested.  Move the local directory aside, update your local copy (or checkout a brand new copy if update doesn't work), then copy your folder over top (to get any changes).  SVN will then pick up the changes and you won't lose all the work everyone else did to that folder since your last update.

Comment: How to fix it under MS Windows?

Comment: @Dimi SVN commands are the same on Linux and on Windows. Open a windows cmd, go to your repo and type `svn up`.

Comment: Pragmateek / Dimi -   Pragmateek's comment worked for me on Windows. I copied the folder i needed locally (unversioned).  Then went into the repo browser and delete the folder directly from the SVN.  I then updated, pasted the file back in a committed and it all was fixed.  Thanks so much  Pragmateek

Answer (score 21):

This happens when you have added a directory that someone else has also added and already committed.

This is something to indicate conflict but at  Directories level (just to understand).

To resolve this, just do `svn update` before committing your changes

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this happens.
Solution:
When you create any new repository must add read.me file to create a default branch(trunk) so that it will find a proper path to push your stuff.
If you create a repository and do not add read. me and if it is blank then upload a file like test.txt and take that uploaded file as latest update in your local folder and then try to push your code from that updated folder. This works for me.